# LocationClient requestLocationUpdates with PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-intent, location, android-pendingintent, intentservice

I'm trying to implement the process explained here: https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

I want to use the PendingIntent variant of the requestLocationUpdates() method, which isn't explained in the aforementioned lesson.

There are 2 problems I've faced:
 - When I receive the intent, it has no usable extras it seems. Also, there are no Helper functions like with Geofences (getTriggeringGeofences) or Activities (extractResult). Do I need to connect to the Location Client again and get the last location onConnect? Won't that be a problem using that in an IntentService?
 - No matter what interval I specify, I only get one immediate intent sent to my IntentService, and no other intent is ever sent. Is this not fully supported?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the code you are using

Answer (score 2):

The documentation explains how the `PendingIntent` is sent [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29). Here are the important bits:

> If the caller supplied a pending intent, then location updates are
>   sent with a key of KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED and a Location value.

This means that when the `PendingIntent` is sent, there should be an extra with the key `LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED`. This extra as a `Location` object.

Comment: @cja Sorry, what makes you think the question is referring to the fused location provider? I can't see any indication of that in the question.

Comment: The mention of LocationClient in the title

Comment: @cja OK, thanks for that. Anyway, OP hasn't responded to my comment nor anything else. So obviously this isn't a priority for him.

Comment: But useful for others @DavidWasser thanks for your answer